# Javascript: Saving a path with a wildcard into a variable

Tags: javascript, regex, variables, wildcard

I would like to save a path with a wildcard into a variable with JS. The path looks something like this:

```
09328402984923kjh234243/2/somename.xml
```

The first and the second part of the path can change, so I would need to have some wildcards there, because the folder-names are not predictable.

I tried something like this with RegEx

```
var position = '\.?/\.?/somename.xml';
```

I'm hanging on this problem for an eternity now and every sample I found on stackoverflow (or elsewhere) does not cover my case. I'm not even sure that RegEx could solve my problem...
Is it possible to save paths with wildcards into variables? And if possible, is RegEx the right way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No idea what you're asking. How do you intend to use your `position` variable?

Comment: What are you using the path for? Where will the two folder values come from?

Comment: If you want to save a regex, use / instead of quotes: `var position = /\.?/\.?/somename.xml/;` -- though I'm not sure if that answers your question because as others have said, it's hard to understand your desired outcome.

Comment: OK, I'll try to explain it better: I'm using the position variable to get the position of a xml file to read it `$.get(position, function(XMLmediaArray)` The problem now ist that the package with the folders and the xml file is dynamically generated and can change, so I would need a variable that has some kind of a wildcard in it like /*/*/somename.xml because the structure is always the same. I don't want to have to adapt the variable every time the folders are newly generated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you ultimately try to accomplish, but if you need to "*dynamically replace*" placeholders in a string, use Javascripts `String.prototype.replace` method.

Example:

```
var position = 'ph1/ph2/somename.xml';

var path_one = '09328402984923kjh234243',
    path_two = '2';
```

and then we can go like

```
position = position
               .replace( 'ph1', path_one )
               .replace( 'ph2', path_two );
```

which would create the result of `09328402984923kjh234243/2/somename.xml`

Comment: That's not exactly what I intended (see my comment above)

Comment: @Lena: I still don't really know what you want to do. "(..) so I would need a variable..." for what purpose ? What do you actually want to do ?

Comment: The variable is not absolutely neccesary. I just thought it would be easier with a variable. It would also be possible to have the path with the wildcards directly here `$.get(*/*/somename.xml, function(XMLmediaArray)` The wildcards are necessary because the path should fit something like 23423jf/2/somename.xml and 3234jf/1/somename.xml because the path can change

Comment: @Lena: If I get you right, the problem comes down to, that no method which wasn't written by yourself or anyone who understands the semantics of a string, is be able to do anything with `"*/*/some.xml"`. So there is no sense to just pass such a wildcarded string to `.get()`. The only sense I can see there is if you have those "partial" data as variables and you want to *create* that whole string from those variables. How that works I answered aboved. If I still don't get you, please come again.

Comment: I think I just learned that Javascript can't do what I want it to do. I wanted the wildcard in the variable to make Javascript "find" the right path, because I don't know it. Just like in batch, when you do commands like */*/*.xml. I'm sorry that my question wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

I think a regex you may be looking for would be `^(.+?)\/(.+?)\/somename\.xml$`. No idea what you want to do with it though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting with the path as a string and want to extract the two folder parts with JavaScript you can do so with;

```
var path = '09328402984923kjh234243/2/somename.xml'
var regex = /[0-9a-zA-Z]*\//g

var folders = path.match(regex)
```

You then have `folders[0]` with the value `09328402984923kjh234243/` and `folders[1]` with the value `2/`.

The regular expression uses the [`g` modifier](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp) at the end to do a global match and pick up all the matches. It is also currently only going to match alpha-numeric characters in your folder names.